# Efeito imagens aumentam quando a pagina carrega

Tags: javascript, html, css

Nesse script as imagens aumentam mas apenas à medida que fazemos scroll
http://tympanus.net/Development/GridLoadingEffects/index8.html

A ideia é toda a vez que a pagina carrega as imagens terem esse efeito sem ter de fazer scrolling

as imagens no meu site estão todas nesse código

```
<img class='alignleft' src='URL DA IMAGEM' />
```

Answer (score 1):

É extremamente simples fazer isso, eu dei uma olhada no efeito das imagens do link e fiz algo parecido, mas sem o scrolling:

```
<img class='alignleft' src='http://tympanus.net/Development/GridLoadingEffects/images/2.jpg'/>
<br />
<img class='alignleft' src='http://tympanus.net/Development/GridLoadingEffects/images/13.png'/>
```

```
img.alignleft{
    animation: sizeEffect .6s;
}

@keyframes sizeEffect{
    0%{
        opacity: .1;
        transform: scale(.4);
    }
    50%{
        opacity: .8;
        transform: scale(1.04);
    }
    100%{
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}
```

Veja o [exemplo completo](http://jsfiddle.net/Kike/KvA2b/1/), com *vendor prefixes* para os diversos browsers).

Comment: Seria interessante além de pu8blicar o link com o exemplo funcionando também publicar o código em sua resposta

Comment: Preferia não fazer isso por ser uma folha de estilo extensa.